# Two power supplies connected together

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I have two switching power supplies:
a step-down that generates 5V from 12-24V, using a TS30042 [(see datasheet)](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjlzfX00dPSAhVpKMAKHWAJCusQFggxMAY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.semtech.com%2Fimages%2Fdatasheet%2Fts3004x.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHrIYvHSwsJDNpVOB-m6xN735fIig&sig2=sJ033vvfAXm9es9c3HDK4A), and a step-up  that generates 5V from a 3.7V battery, using a MIC2876.

The two power supply are enabled alternatively but there is an overlap period of about 1 second in which they are enabled at the same time.

The MIC2876 datasheet states that the output is completly disconnected when the chip is not enabled.

The TS30042 datasheet states that the switching pin tolerates 42V even if the chip is not powered.

My question is: is it safe to connect the two outputs together?
I tried and everything seems to work fine but I am concerned about the reliability.

[image: power supply]

Many thanks for every comment.

Marco

Comment: You could maybe put a Schottky diode (low forward voltage) in series with both of the outputs preventing damages when they are in "switching" mode.

Comment: Should be OK. If you are going to make a bunch of boards, it might be a good idea to test the basic scheme first if you can. Maybe get some evaluation boards and lab power supplies and try out a few different combinations.

Answer (score 0):

It should be "ok" in steady state.

Theoretically when they are tied together like that, whichever one has the higher reference point will drive the circuit, the other will "throttle back", as it were, since it will think the output is too high.

However, if the reference points are really close or overlap in their hysteresis, there is the real possibility that you could set up an oscillation between them. On the load side that would appear as some form of ripple and the chips might get a bit warmer than usual.  As such you may want for force one to be a little higher than the other by offsetting the reference voltage through a shotky diode or resistor divider.

The other got-ya in there is the inductor in the 12V side, if the battery side has the higher reference. And to a lesser extent, vica-versa.

If the 12V is connected first then there will be significant current flowing in the inductor. As such when you plug in the battery and that circuit ramps up, that current may be in excess of the load requirement.

There may be a short voltage spike generated at that time. You need sufficient bulk capacitance to absorb that. It may also be prudent to add an over-voltage limiting Zener across the output just to be sure.

**BTW:** it is common practice to use a switched connector that disconnects the on-board battery circuit when plugging in a wired power source.